# Unable to connect with Oracle Database with invalid/password error ORO-01017

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

Hey I am start my practicing on oracle, on the beginning I am facing this problem, i.e. logon denied, I have just installed both Oracle Database and Oracle SQL developer both, and i am unable to understand what to do.
[image]

Comment: You have `mysql` tagged. Which brand of database are you running here, Oracle or Mysql?

Comment: Well, did you create a "test" user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TEST isn't a default account for Oracle Database XE.

But SYSTEM is.

When you installed/created your XE database, you were prompted for a master password:

[image]

Now, in your connection details, change 'test' to 'system' and change the password to what you supplied to the installation wizard.

As soon as you login, CREATE A NEW USER.

You can use SQL Developer to do this, there is a DBA panel with a CREATE USER dialog.

View - DBA

Add your SYSTEM connection.

Expand the tree, go to Security.

Right-click on USERS.

Give them the roles/privs they need to connect and do things - you can cheat and grant CONNECT, RESOURCE, and DBA roles - this will make you almost a 'god' user.

[image]

Or you can use the SQL Worksheet to manually code it.

But DO NOT ADD OBJECTS to SYS or SYSTEM.

Comment: AWESOME! Congrats and welcome to the wild, wonderful world of Oracle @taimoorpasha!